# Taking Screenshot in macOS Does Not Save Image

Tags: swift, image, screenshot

Below is the code for macOS which intends to take a screenshot of the entire screen and every window within frame then save it to the desktop. When calling the screenshot function nothing occurs.I've tried to logged the image to console to check what is being saved and it appears to have a 1x1 width and height. Is there any idea what could be causing this?

```
func screenshot(){
    let windowImage: CGImage =
        CGWindowListCreateImage(.infinite, .optionIncludingWindow, kCGNullWindowID,
                                [.boundsIgnoreFraming, .nominalResolution])!
    print(windowImage)

    let unixTimestamp = CreateTimeStamp()
    let filename = NSHomeDirectory()
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.desktopDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]
    let homeDirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("/Desktop/screenshot.jpg")
    print(homeDirURL.path)

    let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: windowImage)
    let jpegData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])!

    do {
        try jpegData.write(to: homeDirURL, options: .atomic)
    } catch  {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Image printed to console:

```
<CGImage 0x101116a40> (DP)
<<CGColorSpace 0x600002601ec0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)>
    width = 1, height = 1, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 4 
    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | 0 (default byte order)  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked 
    is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? No
    /Users/adrianalonzo//Desktop/screenshot.jpg
```

**Update: Fixed screenshot parameters. Code now works (:**

```
func screenshot(){
    let windowImage: CGImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRect.infinite, .optionAll, kCGNullWindowID, .nominalResolution)!

    print(windowImage)

    let unixTimestamp = CreateTimeStamp()
    let filename = NSHomeDirectory()
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.desktopDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]
    let homeDirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("/Desktop/screenshot_\(unixTimestamp).jpg")
    print(homeDirURL.path)

    let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: windowImage)
    let jpegData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])!

    do {
        try jpegData.write(to: homeDirURL, options: .atomic)
    } catch  {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}

func CreateTimeStamp() -> Int32
{
    return Int32(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
}
```

Comment: Get permission from the user to save a file at fileUrl.

Comment: @ElTomato Are you referring to kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt? I prompt the user for access and check if permission is given when the app runs. This is done so that I can poll in the background the key combination to trigger the screenshot. Any other ideas?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah fixed that to properly point to desktop now. Any idea why the image dimension is only 1x1?

Comment: nvm got it working. Realized docs defaulted to objective-c. had to switch to Swift to get proper parameters from docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454852-cgwindowlistcreateimage